# Кёнигсберг, ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Почему правильно *Кёнигсбе́рг,* с ударением не на Ё? (Сам думал, что ударение на первый слог.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, это недоразумение.
Там два ударения, с одним его и произнести-то невозможно. 
В таких случаях в словарях ударение над Ё обычно проставляется. 
Но есть одна тонкость. В русском язые слова с двумя ударениями бывают двух типов. С двумя равноправными ударениями (*четыр**ё**хэт**а**жный* - здесь ударение в орфоэпических словарях над Ё стоит). И с побочным ударением (обычно это первое из двух: *рак**е**тон**о**сец* - вот здесь вот Е может и не отмечаться как ударенное).  Видимо, словаристы сочли первое ударение в "*Кёнигсберг*" побочным. Поскольку ситуация с побочным ударением над Ё весьма редкая, возможная только в заимствованиях, для неё, как я понимаю, специальных оговорок не сделали. Отсюда и попала такая форма в словари.

Только так могу объяснить представленную в словарях форму. А то, что там ударение есть - не сомневайтесь. В немецком, кстати, ударными являются все корни составного слова. Это закрепляет подобное и в русском. Но вот произнести это на немецкий манер - с равноправными ударениями - на русском куда сложнее.

Answer (score 1):

**Кё́нигcбépг**; [кё́нигcбépгcкий](http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/kenigsbergskiy/?q=532&n=50123)
Удapeниe пaдaeт нa бyквы **ё, e**. Бyквa «ё» вceгдa являeтcя yдapнoй в cлoвe (иcключeниe cocтaвляют нeкoтopыe инocтpaнныe и cлoжныe cлoвa).

[Возможно, будут интересны слова с двумя буквами **ё**: трёхколёсный, четырёхколёсный, трёхвёдерный ([трёхведёрный](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-109746.htm)), четырёхвёдерный ([четырёхведёрный](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-119109.htm)), [гёмбёц](https://traditio.wiki/%D0%93%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%91%D1%86).]

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы раньше писали через "е"... На LJ есть сердитая статья по этому поводу  ;)

А касательно постулата об ударности "ё" позволю себе растечься мыслию по дереву – как раз смотрел свой словарик на предмет его выполнения. Отклонения в

1) заимствованиях: гёрл(фре́нд), сёгу́н(ат), сёрфинг(и́ст), флёрдора́нж(евый);

2) терминах: гёти́т, лёллинги́т;

3) сложных словах: амёбо(ви́дный), вертолёто(но́сец), вперёд(смотря́щий), дёгте(бето́н),  жёлче(отделе́ние), жёстко(фикси́рованный), колёсо(прока́тный), лепёшко(обра́зный), лёссо(ви́дный), ликёро(во́дочный), [не]платёже(спосо́бный),  перекрёстно(опыля́емый), плёнко(образу́ющий), приёмо(запи́сывающий), самолёто(строи́тельный), тёмно(окра́шенный), чёрно(ко́сая), шёлко(пряди́льный).

В дампе базы данных словаря Хагена приведено больше десятка прилагательных с ударениями типа "зап'ал'ённый". Но означает ли это обозначение ударения "запа́лённая/запалё́нная" или "запа́ленная/запалё́нная", точно сказать не могу. Хотя это могут быть и ошибки.

Comment: Что-то Вы перемудрили: aмё́бoви́дный (http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/amebovidniy/?q=532&n=2308); жeлчeoтдeлéниe (http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/zhelcheotdelenie/?q=532&n=35277); лепё́шкообра́зный (https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-ortho-term-37813.htm); пepeкpё́cтнooпыля́eмый (http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/perekrestnoopilyaemiy/?q=532&n=104051); шё́лкoпpяди́льный (http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/shelkopryadilniy/?q=532&n=158484)...

Comment: *Но означает ли это обозначение ударения "запа́лённая/запалё́нная" или "запа́ленная/запалё́нная",* - второе. Что же касается "постулата", то постулируется не наличие  ударения над **Ё** вообще, а двойное ударения в большинстве заимствованных составных немецких слов. Хотя даже это не абсолют, но тенденция, особенно четко просматривающаяся в словах с немецким суффиксом в первой части - т.е. когда немецкие корни разделены как минимум одним безударным слогом.

Comment: Недомудрил ;) Онлайн-словари типа textologia.ru, конечно, удобны, но вот достоверность хромает – нет гарантии вычитки, робот отвечает по принципу "ё всегда ударно". Взял бумажное (djvu – см. выборки http://ritminme.ru/files/yo_iv.png и http://ritminme.ru/files/yo_av.png ). Мудрит высокоучёная дама: ударение над "ё" ей проставлять влом; что "ё" всегда ударно, в предисловии молчит (как и Аванесов); использует термин "дополнительное ударение" вместо "побочное"... Сравните "самолёто/вертолёто". В "платёжеспособность" одно ударение... Куды программисту податься, чему верить? А словарь нужо́н...

Comment: @Римма Михайлова: Большое спасибо! Ваш разбор подви́г меня  не ограничиваться Аванесовым, но посмотреть и Иванову. Оказалось, что меньшее количество слов на обложке словаря не означает меньше информации... По интересующему меня вопросу кое-что прояснилось.

Comment: @behemothus: Большое спасибо! Т.е. подвижное ударение сопровождается чередованием "ё" и "е".
Под двойным ударением Вы понимаете побочное+главное?

Comment: @Tom d_Cat - Уффф... давйте еще раз. 1. "Двойное ударение" у меня означало слово с двумя ударениями. Такие слова бывают с двумя равноценными ударениями, либо одно из нито является главным. Примеры - в тексте есть. 2.  Да, подвижность ударения в русских словах переводит ударное Ё в безударное Е. Это почти абсолютное правило. 3, Ё бывает безударным только в заимствованиях - и очень редко.. ***Сёдзё***.  в японском нет ударения (такого, каким оно понимается в русском), Где у него ударение, не знаю, но как ни произнеси, оставшийся слог безударный.

Comment: 4. Заимствованимя из немецкого обычно реализуют другую модель: на Ё падает ударение (единственное или одно из двух: основное или побочное, зависит от конкретного слова). К подвижности ударения этот факт не имеет никакого отношения..

Comment: @behemothus: Можно пример русских слов с двумя равноценными ударениями? "Четырё́хэта́жный" словарь Ивановой отвергает ( http://ritminme.ru/files/yo_iv.png ), да и в других источниках встречал "трё̀х..." и "четырё̀х..." для иллюстрации побочных ударений. И в каких словарях "ударение...над Ё стоит"? Его как раз не ставят – типа, и так всё понятно...
Хотя занудствую – для составления словаря поэтической речи такие слова особо не важны. Вряд ли кто будет такое писа́ть:
-! -! -- -! -! -!-- : Душа́ пии́та испыта́ла жа́р томле́ния:
-- -! -- -! -- -!--  : Жё̀сткофикси́ровано сло́ва ударе́ние.
;)

Comment: *Можно пример русских слов с двумя равноценными ударениями? "Четырё́хэта́жный" словарь Ивановой отвергает*  - Это к Ивановой. У Аванесова таких новаций не было. Ударение стоит над Ё у Ожегова, например.

Comment: https://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0390.htm - Аванесов. "платежёспособный" даёт с двумя равносильными ударениями. Почему Иванова отказалась от таких обозначений - и что у ней означает слово "дополнительный" сказаьть трудно. Судя по всему - не "второстепенный".

Comment: Увы, вынужден Вас огорчить – у Аванесова тоже "четырё̀хэта́жный" (ritminme.ru/files/yo_av.png).
У Ивановой в условных знаках прописано: ´ – основное ударение, ` – дополнительное ударение (http://ritminme.ru/files/yo_iv.png). Полагаю, по значку можно считать его побочным.
Да, вижу: есть примеры слов с двумя равносильными ударениями. Хотелось бы понять, на каком основании в одних словах это позволяется, а в других одно из ударений объявляется побочным. У Круковера (http://ritminme.ru/files/yo_kr.png) прослеживается тенденция объявлять побочным первое ударение (если это – не "ё").

Comment: Спасибо, что напомнили Ожегова. Ведь стоит толстенный чёрный том, мой ровесник, на полке, прикрывшись названием "Орфографический словарь русского языка"... А сам орфоэпический, и про ё на 7-й странице написано: "Буква ё в словаре служит указанием одновременно и на произношение и на место ударения, поэтому значок ударения над буквой ё не ставится, напр., ёлочный. В сложных словах типа четырёхэта́жный буква ё показывает только произношение, а не место ударения."